# Remove cookie GA Analytics of URL - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I Have an issue, when directing a new link on my page this link appears with ga cookie, how do I can direct my user without this cookie appearing in the URL?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove \_ga query string from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036210/how-to-remove-ga-query-string-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GTM:

On the google-analytics tag, check the checkbox "Enable overriding settings in this tag"

[image: Click To See Img]

Then go to More Settings > Fields to Set: Add a new Field Name equal to allowLinker and the value to false.

[image: Click To See Img]

Comment: did as shown but the changes didn't work and the ga cookie kept showing up Could you help me?